# Line Breaks in Joomla 5 language fles

Tags: joomla-4.x, language, joomla-5.x

It seems that a fresh install of J5.0.1 does not allow line breaks in the text value part in a component language file. Is this correct?

In previous versions you could break long text strings over several lines which was good for readability in editors that don't word-wrap. Any line breaks were converted to spaces.

Now when using a previously good language file v5.0.1 simply refuses to load it unless you remove all the line breaks, Surely this is a bug? Its going to be a pain to have to strip line breaks from all language files to make them j5 compatible.

Answer (score 1):

This B/C break has been introduced as part of [security fix](https://developer.joomla.org/security-centre/919-20231101-core-exposure-of-environment-variables.html) in 5.0.1 and 4.4.1. It is possible to fix the vulnerability without introducing this break. A [patch](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/42463) has been submitted to mitigate the issue. However, maintainers have decided to keep it this way.

Comment: grrr - this is really really bad news. It should be fixed by the B/C plugin at the very least. For now it is breaking perfectly good j4.x and 5.0.0 language files without explanation. J4 to J5 was supposed to be backwards compatible and there is a fix for this available in the patch you link.
It seems the "maintainers" are not invovled in using real sites with real language files. Stupidity. (this is by way of pointing out a problem with the reply)